# CMTI of a push pull converter

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, emc, common-mode

According to this [article](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt790b/slyt790b.pdf?ts=1695895111376&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F), a push converter has good immunity against Common Mode transient :

[image]

It is said "The flux generated by the current flowing in one primary coil cancels the flux generated in the second coil, resulting in a low impedance path to the primary supply" I agree with this. And then " This prevents the common mode current from overloading primary switches Q1 and Q2" ? This is a bit contradoctory ? If it is a low impedance path ? What I do not understand ?

[image]

The above figure suppose that the current will go through the voltage source. It could be possible and then it will not overload the Q1 and Q2 switch, but what is the reason ? Why it couldnot go in the opposite way ? Or why one could go in Q1 and the other in the voltage source ? In this case the two flux will not cancel each other. (voltage source is seen as ground in AC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the author is saying is that the undesirable injection of a surge current (due to capacitive coupling) from the secondary into the two primaries will naturally flow to the primary power rail (\$V_{IN}\$). In other words, it won't pass into the main primary transistors because of the way the transformer primary is wound.

Because transformers are imperfect devices, there will be a small current that tries to pass into the transistors but, this will be solely down to how badly coupled the two primaries are. If they were perfectly coupled then all the surge current from the secondary would, by transformer action, pass to \$V_{IN}\$.

Comment: Thank you Andy, You mean that the physics will tend to minimize the magnectic energy into the transformer and so it will tend to make the both current to pass to Vin in order to cancel the total flux produced by the two windings ?

Comment: @Jess that's a good way of putting it, yes.